# AlphaFold.ipynb running process errors

Tags: process, runtime-error

I'm getting the following errors (just the last portion of the run that identified the errors). I have previously run this through CoLab successfully, but suddenly this error is now popping up immediately in the first run task (Install Third-Party software). I'm using a MacOS to run this. I'm pretty new to running this I should mention.

See below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-a5fc66cf3ead> in <cell line: 22>()
     40       PATH=get_ipython().run_line_magic('env', 'PATH')
     41       get_ipython().run_line_magic('env', 'PATH=/opt/conda/bin:{PATH}')
---> 42       get_ipython().run_line_magic('shell', 'conda install -qy conda==4.13.0            && conda install -qy -c conda-forge              python=3.10              openmm=7.7.0              pdbfixer')
     43       pbar.update(80)
     44 

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2416                 kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2417             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2418                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2419             return result
   2420 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_system_commands.py in _shell_line_magic(line)
     65   """
     66   result = _run_command(line, clear_streamed_output=False)
---> 67   result.check_returncode()
     68   return result
     69 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_system_commands.py in check_returncode(self)
    135   def check_returncode(self):
    136     if self.returncode:
--> 137       raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
    138           returncode=self.returncode, cmd=self.args, output=self.output
    139       )

CalledProcessError: Command 'conda install -qy conda==4.13.0            && conda install -qy -c conda-forge              python=3.10              openmm=7.7.0              pdbfixer' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I've updated python, which I don't think I needed to do based on the above. I've also just purchase 100 computing units to run this, but not sure how that effects running the program. I honestly don't know where to start to solve this problem as it's never happened before on the exact same computer.